# Flutter: Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, flutter

When i run the sample project of flutter on ios it is running, but when i run my own project it is giving me this error

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2023-07-24 09:24:09.941 xcodebuild[4470:41705] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
2
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B1F48EAC-3F7D-424B-A0D6-9B55A6CBEFDF, OS:16.4, name:iPhone 14 Pro Max }
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/mm/l0yn5ttj3qq5xl9tj3sx8m9c0000gp/T/flutter_tools.WVfV4r/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir8K3kvE/temporary_xcresult_bundle
    ld: file not found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/***/Desktop/***/***/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.4.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    /Users/***/Desktop/***/***/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.4.99. (in target 'Toast' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
warning: Run script build phase 'Thin Binary' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    /Users/***/Desktop/***/***/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 11.0 to 16.4.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle' from project 'Pods')
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/mm/l0yn5ttj3qq5xl9tj3sx8m9c0000gp/T/flutter_tools.WVfV4r/flutter_ios_build_temp_dir8K3kvE/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Error (Xcode): File not found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14 Pro Max.
```

i delete the `podfile.lock` file reinstall the pods but still same error. please help how to fix it.

Comment: @DarshanKachhadiya how to re generate it?

Comment: i deleted the ios folder and run flutter create on project terminal, but it is giving this error ```No option specified for the output directory.
Create a new Flutter project.```

Comment: run command flutter create .   [flutter create with dot]

Comment: try this 
cd project &

flutter create .

Comment: i regenetate ios folder now, but still same error as i posted

Comment: Open your ios/Podfile and set the iOS deployment target to a supported version
- like : platform :ios, '11.0'

Comment: i did that, same error. And when i run the project from Xcode it gives this error ```Error (Xcode): File not found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a

Error (Xcode): Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, all I did was clean the iOS App by opening it on Xcode and pressing Cmd + Shift + K